# Sharing git between different users

Tags: git, version-control

I currently have a git setup where git is a user on my linux box. /home/git exists and there are several git repositories in /home/git. The git user has a shell of /usr/bin/git-shell. If a user needed access to the repository, I'd just grab their SSH DSA public key and embed it into /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys and they'd be able to work with the repository.

The problem is now that I need a second repository that needs to support a different set of users. I don't want to create a new account for each repository that I create.

What's the best way of keeping this working with SSH? (the easiest way of all the sharing techniques I've seen that git supports)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might consider using [gitosis](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way).

Main advantages are:

- only one ssh user (might be a disadvantage)
- users identified by SSH keys
- users and repos created on the fly by using git itself

Comment: there is any way to do it using only git? i mean just with user accounts, ssh server and git.

Comment: @ignatius: sure; if a user can ssh into server he can do anything there - ie. use git ;) You can also share git repo by using git-daemon command.

Answer (score 0):

Beside [Gitosis](http://eagain.net/gitweb/?p=gitosis.git) (mentioned in [Marcin Gil answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828278/sharing-git-between-different-users/1828295#1828295)), , which requires Python and setuptools, best known probably from seminal [Hosting Git repositories, The Easy (and Secure) Way](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way) blog post, and described in [Chapter 4.7 of "Pro Git" book](http://progit.org/book/ch4-7.html), there is also similar **[Gitolite](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)** tool; it is written in Perl, and is quite new.